# How to fill 4" width gap between the walls and alcove bathtub door

Tags: bathtub, door-frame

I'm trying to install a full width alcove bathtub sliding glass door. Problem is the width of pre-built tub doors, especially those at budget price level such as  [this one](https://www.lowes.ca/product/shower-doors/sterling-standard-59-in-w-x-56437-in-h-silver-bathtub-door-26732), seemed to be standardized at  max 60" but the width of my bathtub and alcove is 64".

How to address the 4" shortage both cost-effectively and aesthetically? Presumably I am looking for a commodity product preferably available in local hardware stores to fill the gap. Example product link would be helpful. I have thought about using U-shaped aluminum channels but most channels are under 1" width. There are high-end or custom-built tub doors fitting 64" but they cost over $800, which is over my budget.

Comment: maybe you can find some the right size second-hand?

Comment: Unfortunately, "shopping" questions are off-topic here. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: @DanielGriscom, this question is more about cost-effective solution than shopping for a specific product brand, despite it is likely to involve such activity.

Comment: @Jasen, thanks for the idea but that option is usually not readily available, especially in less populated areas.

Comment: 2 inch by 1 inch box section aluminum is readily available on the internets. Bonus points if you get the exact size that the shower door will slot over. Tip: drill a small weep hole at the bottom of each of the box sections so you don't get standing water

Comment: @aloysius Defenestrate , work that into an answer I will up vote, I was thinking of a spacer but aluminum tube was better than what I was thinking.+

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the only way to approach this, but since many shower doors have a U shaped channel that covers another U shaped channel (that's been attached to the wall), you could use box section aluminum -- 2"x1" (assuming that the 1" dimension meshes well with your chosen door) on both sides. Your local metal supplier probably won't have this in stock, but you could order from them or the internet generally.

Tip: drill a weep hole at the bottom of the 2x1 that drains to the tub so that you don't inadvertently get standing water in the tube.